# error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: software-installation, python

I ran the following commands in the terminal for a 14.04 Ubuntu server

```
$ cd reddit/r2
$ python setup.py build
$ sudo python setup.py develop
```

After the last line I get an error, please see bellow the lines from the terminal.

```
root@dedi-fr-32312:~# cd reddit/r2
root@dedi-fr-32312:~/reddit/r2# python setup.py build
Cannot find Cython. Skipping Cython build.
Cannot find Baseplate. Skipping Thrift build.
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
root@dedi-fr-32312:~/reddit/r2# sudo python setup.py develop
Cannot find Cython. Skipping Cython build.
Cannot find Baseplate. Skipping Thrift build.
running develop
running egg_info
writing requirements to r2.egg-info/requires.txt
writing r2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to r2.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to r2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to r2.egg-info/entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'r2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'r2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Cfilters.so -> 
Creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/r2.egg-link (link to .)
r2 0.0.0dev is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /root/reddit/r2
Processing dependencies for r2==0.0.0dev
Searching for python-snappy
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-snappy/
Best match: python-snappy 0.5
Downloading     https://pypi.python.org/packages/70/fa/621594e313b2b9074585af63668f7a314e4d69df536ab592e6e1e353/python-snappy-0.5.tar.gz#md5=044fb0ac21888c0b4eee0c4f15e75504
Processing python-snappy-0.5.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-nSKzTM/python-snappy-0.5/setup.cfg
Running python-snappy-0.5/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-nSKzTM/python-snappy-0.5/egg-dist-tmp-EgXgE7
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
snappymodule.cc:31:22: fatal error: snappy-c.h: No such file or directory
#include <snappy-c.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
root@dedi-fr-32312:~/reddit/r2#
```

Some help to fix it?

Comment: should it be python3?

Comment: @Tim, The Guideline ask for "2.7.x".

Comment: Solved. Puthon-snappy was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765155/error-setup-script-exited-with-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-wit?noredirect=1#comment1142594_765155) by [OP](https://askubuntu.com/users/537478/esembled-intl):

> Solved. Python-snappy was missing